# Confusion about NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios5.1

Update: I was able to get the date converted from the server json to 2012/09/05 10:45

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


    for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
        NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];

        for (myDays in slot){

            if ([[self.myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){

                NSDate *newDate = [df dateFromString:[self.myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];
                if (newDate){
                    [self.timesArray addObject:newDate];

                }
                NSLog(@"these are the returned newdates: %@",newDate);
                NSLog(@"This is the timesArray: %@", self.timesArray);
            }


        }        
    }
```

My NSLog of These are still returning null and my This is the timesArray is ()
I am not understanding what is wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nothing is being added to the NSArray because the date formatter is barfing on your input and giving you nil instead of an NSDate back.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your inputs are valid?

Also, your first log only says that the date formatter got allocated--not that it will produce results for your inputs.

Ran a quick test, it looks like your problem is in the timezone portion of the date. The following code will return: `date is 2012-10-04 16:15:00 +0000`

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss V"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"2012-10-04 09:15:00 PT"];
NSLog(@"date is %@", date);
```

You can check explicitly to see if the date formatter can get a date from your string like this:

```
    __autoreleasing NSDate* date2 = nil;
    NSRange dateRange = NSMakeRange(0, [@"2012-10-04 09:15:00 PT" length]);
    __autoreleasing NSError* err = nil;

    BOOL canMakeDate = [df getObjectValue:&date2 forString:@"2012-10-04 09:15:00 PT" range:&dateRange error:&err];
    NSLog(@"could get a date %@, from range %@. Got %@", canMakeDate ? @"YES" : @"NO", NSStringFromRange(dateRange), date2);
```

Since the date string is coming from server-side I would suggest investigating how it's sending down timezones and change them manually on your end.  Not pretty but regexs are your friend.

Comment: I think they are, how would I check to make sure?

Comment: The Unicode specs are available [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Time_Zone_Fallback)

Comment: I would put self.myDays objectForKey in where 2012-10-04 09:15:00 PT is?

Answer (score 0):

`dateFromString:` returns `nil` when it can't convert the string into a date. Your `V` format matches a time zone in generic non-location format, like "PT" for Pacific Time. What you're supplying to describe the timezone is completely different, hence gibberish for the formatter.

I believe that is a format that `NSTimezone` understands, so you can extract the string, create an `NSTimezone`, use that to get the offset from UTC, and then replace the "America/Los_Angeles" with "-0700" or "-0800" as appropriate, then parse that out using the "Z" format specifier.

For more on date formatting, see the [ICU User Guide section](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Comment: Like this?  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss V"];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

Comment: No. It is unlikely the time zone sent down by the server is your system time zone. Setting the formatter time zone just supplies default TZ info in the event the date string itself does not.

Comment: I found this too: NSTimezone: Note that, strictly, time zone database entries such as “America/Los_Angeles” are IDs not names. An example of a time zone name is “Pacific Daylight Time”. Although many NSTimeZone method names include the word “name”, they refer to IDs.

Comment: Which is why NSTimeZone is what you want. It can translate those IDs into offsets from UTC and maybe proper names, as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful of is using `YYYY` in your date format. `YYYY` is not the same as `yyyy`.

`YYYY` = Year (in “Week of Year” based calendars). This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. May not always be the same value as calendar year.

`yyyy` = returns the the year in the format 2012 (Gregorian).

You are also specifying that your TimeZone will be in a short format `V` (PT), try using Long format `VVVV` United States (Los Angeles)

Comment: still null when trying your solution